# eclipse oxygen scala IDE で HelloWorld できない

Tags: eclipse, scala

```
package Sample01

object HelloScala {
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    println("Hello scala");
  }
}
```

上記のような単純なものですが、なんとか実行してみると以下のようなメッセージが出ます。

```
エラー: メイン・クラスHelloScalaが見つからなかったかロードできませんでした
```

何とも言いようがないくだらない質問ですがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: ryshさん回答有難うございます。Scala IDE 4.7.0-RC1の方で正常動作確認しています。どうもバグだろうと思います。今回はこれで終わりにします。再現しづらい質問の様でこれ以上試しているのが馬鹿げているようで非常に気になっていました。有難うございました。

Answer (score 0):

> package Sample01

の行を削除すると実行できるみたいですが、理由まではわかりませんでした。